# Why does map() get 2 arguments in this case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, children

Could you help me, please, I can't understand why there are 2 arguments in the map()

```
Children.map(this.props.children, child =>              
        <button>{child} </button>
```

I supposed that this construction should work

```
Children.map(child =>           
        <button>{child} </button>
```

But it doesn't.

Comment: That syntax doesn't look valid. More than one argument requires parentheses.

Comment: Is this using [`React.Children`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren)? Don't confuse it with the array method [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: first argument is what to map over and second is the mapping function

Comment: Yeah, that React.Children

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`React.Children` map API takes the first argument as the children array to iterate on and the second argument as the callback function that is called with each of the iterated children

Unlike the normal map which is the prototype of the Array constructor function, in the above case `map` is a function defined for the Children Object and needs to be passed with the array it has to iterate on